# Iterate through array in c manually

Tags: c, arrays

I have a string array of 10 words and I want to display them.

However, I want the user to press a key and the next values are displayed.

I.e, it should display a, then the user presses a key and it displays b.

How can I achieve this?

```
 char destination[10][10]

 for (i=0; i<10; i++){

    printf(Enter a name: );
    scanf( "%s", name[i])
 }


 for (i=0; i<10; i++){

    printf(" Name %d: %s", i, name[i]);
    getch();
 }
```

Comment: Show your code. How could we help without seeing your code ?

Comment: What is your target environment? Embed (microprocessor)? Console (CUI using standard input/output)? GUI (with what OS/library?)?

Comment: console environment

Comment: how do i paste my code, directly or using intermediary medium, eg pastebin?

Comment: @Kem paste your code here, but only the relevant parts if your code is huge.

Comment: destination should be name... thats not what i have in program

Comment: Your code does not compile. Once the syntax errors etc. corrected your code works fine.

Comment: @michael walz even if i have parallel arrays it will work?

Comment: I have no idea what you want, maybe you should get your question translated from your mother tongue to english and edit it.

Comment: I speak english

Comment: this is what I'm saying.

Comment: When the first element is displayed and i press a key to view the next element, it skips the the proceeding one and goes to the next. For example, if A is being displayed and i press <enter> expecting to see B, it just flashes B and prints C. Understand now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, nor what your actual problem is, but this works fine here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {

    char name[10][10];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {

      printf("Enter a name : ");
      scanf("%s", name[i]);
    }

  for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {

    printf(" Name %d: %s", i, name[i]);
    getch();
  }    
}
```

Comment: when i press a key instead of the next value it quickly displays it then goes to the next, so its like:  display A, briefly shows B,  display C.